# CSS file is not impacting while Load html file using jQuery load function

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I want to include the html file in another html file. I am able to load the page but (jquery-mobile) css is not impacting in included page.

I want to separate the login functionality from the test. so i want to implement like this.

Please find the code below.

Test.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Application</title> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.1.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>        
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body> 
<div id="content"></div>        
 </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   user.loginDo();       
 });
```

Login.html

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Sign On</h1>    
</div>
<div id="logo_pos">
    <center><img src="images/test.jpg" alt="splash"/></center>
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="userid" id="luserid" ><strong>UserId : </strong></label>
    <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" value="" class="logon" placeholder="Username" required/>

</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="password" id="lpassword"><strong>Password :</strong></label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="logon" value="" placeholder="Password" required/>
</div>

<div class="ui-body">
    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">                            
        <div class="ui-block-a"><a data-role="button" id="loginbtn" data-theme="b">Login</a></div>                          
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

login.js

```
 user.loginDo = function() {
  console.log("Inside Login");
  $("#content").load("Login.html");
 };
```

I want to apply jquery-mobile .css to Login Page. Please help me out on this..

Comment: Search on your favourite search engine for "jquery mobile dynamic content".

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to redraw the page.

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/force_redraw

```
$("#content").forceRedraw();
```

Comment: I am unable to find or download the plugin, could you please let me know where can i get it?

Comment: Hm, I'm sorry but it looks like jquery.com is doing major changes to their plugin page. See: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/12/08/what-is-happening-to-the-jquery-plugins-site/